# Python effective integer size

Tags: python, integer, long-integer, integer-arithmetic

For example in C#, C++, Java or JavaScript effective int size is 32 bits. If we want to calculate some large number, for example, 70 bits, we should use some software features ([Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)).

Python has a very tricky integer internal boundless representation and I'm can not figure out what is the most efficient int size for integer arithmetic.

In other words, do we have some int size, say 64 bits, for effective ints usage?

Or it does not matter is it `16`, `32`, `64` or `some random bits count`, and Python will work for all these ints with the same efficiency?

In short does Python always uses Arbitrary-precision arithmetic or for 32\64 it uses hardware arithmetic?

Comment: You can use numpy, if size matters. Here you can choose from e.g. uint32 and uint64.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, Python integers *are not sized*, which you seem to already understand?

Comment: @Stefan or alternatively, you can use the `array` module for primitive, numeric arrays which sometimes suffices (if you are going to do any heavy-duty processing, then probably numpy is what you want)

Comment: As far as you are concerned, the bit length of any particular `int` object is an implementation detail. I don't understand what you are asking here "do we have some int size, say 64 bits, for effective ints usage?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga we have two kinds of arithmetic. `Hardware`, for integers with size  smaller or equal CPU's word. `Software`, when we can calculate large numbers (larger that CPU's word), but in a slow manner using some code. Does  Python always use slow software arithmetic? Or does it use hardware arithmetic for 32/64 bits?

Comment: You should add that to your question, because that is a question about CPython internals.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga done. Do you know the asnwer?

Comment: No, but here is the implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c EDIT: And here, I believe, is where addition is implemented: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fff3c28052e6b0750d6218e00acacd2fded4991a/Objects/longobject.c#L3073

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I can understand implementation I would not ask the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPython's `int`, in Python 3, is represented as a sign-magnitude array of values, where each element in the array represents 15 or 30 bits of the magnitude, for 32 and 64 bit Python builds respectively. This is an implementation detail, but a longstanding one (it was originally 15 all the time, but it was found to be an easy win to double the size and number of used bits per "digit" in the array when working on 64 bit systems). It has optimizations for `int`s that fit into a single (or sometimes two) such array values (it extracts the raw value from the array and performs a single CPU operation, skipping loops and algorithms that apply to the arbitrary length case), and on 64 bit builds of CPython, that currently means values with magnitude of 30 bits or less are generally optimized specially (with 60 bit magnitudes occasionally having fast paths).

That said, there's rarely a reason to take this into account; CPython interpreter overhead is pretty high, and it's pretty hard to imagine a scenario where manually breaking down a larger operation into smaller ones (incurring more interpreter overhead to do many small operations at the Python layer) would outweigh the much smaller cost of Python doing the array-based operations (even without special fast paths) at the C layer. The exceptions to this rule would all rely on non-Python-`int`-solutions, using fixed size `numpy` arrays to vectorize the work, and largely following C rules at that point (since `numpy` arrays are wrappers around raw C arrays most of the time).

Comment: I assume, an example of the optimization is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fff3c28052e6b0750d6218e00acacd2fded4991a/Objects/longobject.c#L3073) where it checks `if (Py_ABS(Py_SIZE(a)) <= 1 && Py_ABS(Py_SIZE(b)) <= 1) { return PyLong_FromLong(MEDIUM_VALUE(a) + MEDIUM_VALUE(b));}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yup. `MEDIUM_VALUE` is a macro that unpacks a single element from the underlying array (and fixes up its sign, since the array value isn't signed itself). So it's just unpacking both, adding them with a normal CPU instruction, then repacking them into a new `int`.

Comment: Does it mean that python 64 build work with integers efficiently only in range -2^29 to 2^29 -1?

Comment: @NoNameQA: The range is `-2³⁰ - 1` to `2³⁰ - 1`; the array holds a 30 bit unsigned magnitude in each element, and the sign is encoded in the size of the array (negative numbers store a negative length for the array). The idea being that overflow can't occur even in multiplication when both operands are small enough to fit in a 32 bit range, and the work is being done with 64 bit operands. The 30 bit (instead of 31 bit) thing is due to the relative ease of converting the algorithms that worked with 15 out of 16 bits by simply doubling all the numbers.

Comment: You can see the effect with `sys.getsizeof`; on my 64 bit build `sys.getsizeof(-(2**30) - 1)` is 28 (bytes), but `sys.getsizeof(-(2**30))` is 32; the array had to expand when the high bit moved to the 31st bit.

Comment: Amazing answer! So weird behavior. Thank you!

Comment: Just for posterity, I mistyped a bit when putting in the numbers. The range is `-2³⁰ + 1` to `2³⁰ - 1`, and it's `sys.getsizeof(-(2**30 - 1))` (or equivalently, `sys.getsizeof(-(2**30) + 1)`) that has a size of 28 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the python struct library and pack a simple number then attempt to read the length back, the result will be in bytes:

```
import struct
size_int = len(struct.pack('i',0))
print(size_int)
```

> 4

Comment: As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment), your are here printing the value of `sizeof(int)` returned by the C compiler used to compile your Python interpreter, which is not the internal size used for integers by Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sys.getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) which returns the total size of any object including any garbage collector overhead, though this is apparently not the size of the internal piece of data used by the CPU for any hardware operation.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(12345678)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(1234567890)
32
>>> sys.getsizeof(1234567890123456789)
36
>>> sys.getsizeof(12345678901234567890123456789)
40
```

This may not be your question, but I guess there is no point in Python to infer this size if your plan is to make your code more efficient.